# Error compilación Flappy bird unity

Tags: c#, unity

> Assets/Scripts/Bird.cs(40,13): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member t.Stop();

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Timers;
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement speed
    public float speed = 1;


    // Flap force
    public float force = 100;

    public double Interval = 10000;

    private Timer t;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
      // Fly towards the right
      GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
      t = new Timer(Interval);
      t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
      t.Start();
  }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Flap
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        t.Stop();
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    private static void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            ///
            /// aqui pones el codigo para mostrar que gano
            ///
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes es debido a que estás intentando acceder a una variable de la clase desde un método [estático](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

Deberías declarar la función como no estática para solucionar el error:

```
private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marc